# How do I configure networking when using XEN on 12.04 Server

Tags: networking, virtualization, xen

I'm following this guide, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenProposed, and I'd like to setup a static IP address, but I don't know how. I'm using 12.04 Server.

This is the step I'm having trouble at (I'm using eth1):

```
Edit /etc/network/interfaces, and make it look like this:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto xenbr0
iface xenbr0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

I do this, and here is my output from ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:a4:f8:79:20  
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:478264 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2895 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:46470058 (46.4 MB)  TX bytes:214620 (214.6 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:fa000000-fa012800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:a4:f8:79:20  
      inet addr:192.168.1.122  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::217:a4ff:fef8:7920/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:471842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2795 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:37005780 (37.0 MB)  TX bytes:182010 (182.0 KB)
```

So how do I give this system a static IP address? Sorry, I'm not that familiar with networking on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

use the instructions [here](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Network_Configuration_Examples_%28Xen_4.1+%29) for Debian. The link contains an example for configuring a static IP address by editing  /etc/network/interfaces to contain the following lines:

```
iface xenbr0 inet static
bridge_ports eth0
address 192.168.1.2
broadcast 192.168.1.255
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I edited my answer as recommended.